# Chrome extension - Check if context/page is a options, Content Script devtools or windows?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3, web-extension

Working on library, which executes differently in different contexts/pages i.e Popup, Options, Devtools, ContentScript & Windows for which we need to know which context the library is running in and execute accordinly.

So, something like this :..

```
const isOptionsPage = checkForOptionsPage();
const isPopupPage = checkForPopupPage();
const isContentScript = checkForContentScript();
const isDevtools = checkForDevtools();

function myLibrary() {
  if (isOptionsPage) {
    // execute code for options page
    //
    //
  } else if (isPopupPage) {
    // execute code for Popup page
    //
    //
  } else if (isContentScript) {
    // execute code for Content Script 
    //
    //
  } else if (isDevtools) {
    // execute code for Devtools page
    //
    //
  }
  // Common Execution
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to infer from availability of `chrome` properties and compare `location.href` to the values in manifest.json.

```js
const m = chrome.runtime.getManifest();
const isContentScript = !!(!chrome.tabs && chrome.extension && chrome.runtime.getURL);
const isOffscreen = !!(!chrome.tabs && !chrome.extension && chrome.runtime.getURL);
const isOptionsPage = !!chrome.tabs &&
  location.href === chrome.runtime.getURL(m.options_page || m.options_ui?.page || '');
// this will be wrong when using chrome.action.setPopup with a different path
const isPopupPage = !!chrome.tabs &&
  location.href === chrome.runtime.getURL((m.action || m.browser_action)?.default_popup);
const isDevtools = !!chrome.devtools;
```

Comment: These work great. Also, are these temporary hacks or will work fine in future as well ??

Comment: No hacks. All conditions are based on the intended availability of API in Chrome/Firefox and any compatible browsers. But some browsers like Orion and maybe Safari weirdly expose all API in all contexts.